# Delete all observations of a group after a variable changes

Tags: sql

I would like to delete all observations from a group after a variable changes by keeping the first occurrence of this variable, regardless of the following values.

What I have

```
id  A
a   0 
a   0 
a   0
b   0
b   0
b   1
c   1
c   1
c   1
d   1
d   0
d   0
d   0
```

What I want

```
id  A
a   0 
a   0 
a   0
b   0
b   0
b   1
c   1
d   1
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Does the value ever change back?

Comment: Without any additional columns to determine the order you have no guaranuee to get the same order of items and thus are not able to determine when a value changes for the first time

Comment: Thanks for showing us what you have and what you want. Can you post what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  So there is no first or next value *unless a column specifies the ordering*.  Let me assume there is one.

One way to express this uses correlated subqueries:

```
select t.id, t.a
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.A
              from <table> t2
              where t2.id = t.id
              order by t2.<ordering column>
              fetch first 1 row only
             ) as first_a
      from <table> t
     ) t
where t.<ordering_column> < (select min(t3.ordering_column)
                             from table t3
                             where t3.a <> t.first_a
                            );
```